# Swift writing map, length, filter as reduce

Tags: swift, function

As an exercise, I'm trying to write map, length and filter as a reduce function.

```
func map<T>(array: [T], f: (T->T)) -> [T] {
    return array.reduce([]) {
        (var seed, value) in
        seed.append(f(value))
        return seed
    }
}

func length<T>(array: [T]) -> Int {
    return array.reduce(0){ (x,_) in x + 1 }
}

func filter<T>(array: [T], predicate: (T->Bool)) -> [T]{
    return array.reduce([]){
        (var seed, value) in
        if predicate(value){
            seed.append(value)
        }
        return seed
    }
}
```

Is this the most elegant syntax I can use to rewrite those functions as reduce? 
2nd question: map takes a function f:(T->T)
Basically the type says I can only return something of type T, but what if the function I write transforms type T to a Bool, or and Int... 
How do I accomplish this?
Seems like map doesn't exist

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a mapping which transforms a type `T` into a (possibly different) type `S`
simply use *two* type placeholders:

```
func map<T, S>(array: [T], f: (T->S)) -> [S] {
    return array.reduce([]) {
        (var seed, value) in
        seed.append(f(value))
        return seed
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let x = map([1, 2, 3], f: { String($0) })
print(x) // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Whether this *"is this the most elegant syntax"* is also a
matter of personal opinion. If you replace the `append()` method
by array concatenation with `+` then the `seed` parameters needs
not be variable:

```
func map<T, S>(array: [T], f: (T->S)) -> [S] {
    return array.reduce([]) {
        (seed, value) in
        seed + [f(value)]
    }
}
```

Which can be written with shorthand parameter names as

```
func map<T, S>(array: [T], f: (T->S)) -> [S] {
    return array.reduce([]) { $0 + [ f($1) ] }
}
```

Similarly:

```
func filter<T>(array: [T], predicate: (T->Bool)) -> [T]{
    return array.reduce([]) { predicate($1) ? $0 + [ $1 ] : $0 }
}
```

Just note that an implementation of `map()` and `filter()` using
`reduce()` (instead of a loop) is quite ineffective because a *new array* is created in each reduction step. See for example

- [Arrays, Linked Lists and Performance](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/08/03/arrays-linked-lists-and-performance/)

for an analysis. For an *exercise* (as you said) it is fine, just
don't use something like this in production).

Comment: Muchas gracias, thanks! Exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for. Swift is a strange landscape in the beginning ;)

Comment: Strange landscape that inspired you to attempt this!?! :)

Comment: Apparently there does exist something like transducers ;) Excellent way to acquire some basic knowledge about swift.

Comment: anyways to implement a map without the ```reduce``` ?

Comment: can anyone can give me an example how to implement the filter function above? Let's say I have an array `let animals = ["cat", "dog", "sheep", "dolphin", "tiger"]` and I want the function to return an array of strings that have 3 characters

Comment: @HienQuangTran: `let filtered = animals.filter { $0.characters.count == 3 }`.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks but I mean can we do something like `let filteredAnimals =  filter( //initiate the function...)` because the function above is just a customized filter function using reduce. Therefore I don't think it comes with an array type, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

extension CollectionType

```
extension CollectionType {
func MyMap<T>(transform: (Self.Generator.Element) -> T) -> [T] {
    let list = self.reduce([T]()) { (var seed, value) in
        seed.append(transform(value))
        return  seed
    }
    return list
}}
```

then use  [1,2,3].MyMap({ $0 + 1})